# acts_as_votable upvote method generating 'get' request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, heroku, acts-as-votable

I have acts_as_votable configured like so to generate upvoting and downvoting of content in my app:

partial:

```
<div class="btn-group">
        <%= link_to like_link_path(link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-success btn-sm" do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
          Upvote
          <%= link.get_upvotes.size %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to dislike_link_path(link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-warning btn-sm" do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
          Downvote
          <%= link.get_downvotes.size %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
  def upvote
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    @link.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def downvote
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    @link.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

routes:

```
resources :links do
    member do
      put "like", to: "links#upvote"
      put "dislike", to: "links#downvote"
    end
  end
```

Although I illicitly call for a put request in both my routes and view, my logs show that my browser is trying to make a get request:

```
Jan 12 16:43:24 quotesappp app/web.1:  Started GET "/links/1/dislike" for 96.248.110.224 at 2016-01-13 00:43:23 +0000
```

This was not an issue previously when I was testing locally, but on deployment to Heroku, it is not registering a put request. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?